# Why won't TortoiseHG post comments to Bugzilla

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bugzilla, issue-tracking

I have a Bugzilla system that has been running for a while and I recently started using  TortoiseHG , I want to use the Bugzilla Extension to update the comments.

I've set it up as per the Mercurial site   [Here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugzillaExtension) but its not posting to the bug.

Here is a copy of the Mercurial.ini I am using

```
# Generated by TortoiseHg settings dialog
[tortoisehg]
ui.language = en_GB
[ui]
merge = kdiff3
[extensions]
hgext.bugzilla = 
zeroconf = 

[hooks]
# run bugzilla hook on every change pulled or pushed in here
incoming.bugzilla = python:hgext.bugzilla.hook

[bugzilla]
# REQUIRED ITEMS:
host = http://192.168.10.33/bugtracker/ # mysql server where bugzilla database lives 
password = xxxxx   # user's password
version = 2.22.2  # version of bugzilla installed

# OPTIONAL ITEMS:
bzuser = peter.francis@xxx.com    # fallback bugzilla user name to record comments with
#   db = bugs       # database to connect to
#   notify = ...    # command to run to get bugzilla to send mail
regexp = [Bb]ug (\d+)   # regexp to match bug ids (must contain one "()" group)
#   strip = 0       # number of slashes to strip for url paths
#   style = ...     # style file to use when formatting comments
#   template = ...  # template to use when formatting comments
#   timeout = 5     # database connection timeout (seconds)
#   user = bugs     # user to connect to database as
#   [web]
#   baseurl = http://hgserver/... # root of hg web site for browsing commits
```

Has anyone else done this and can offer advise ?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be configuring this extension in the `hgrc` file of the repository you are working with instead of in your `mercurial.ini`?